# get Current User React Symfony

Tags: reactjs, api, symfony

I am using react in existing symfony project.
I am using the standard authentication system generated by **make:auth** (Without token). I have installed API platform and I want to retrieve a set of data current. I created a custom controller to do it but, isn't work
This is my custom controller

```
    protected $em;
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Security $security)
    {
        $this->em=$em;
        $this->security=$security;
    }
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $user=$this->security->getUser();
        return $this->em->getRepository(Paths::class)->findAllProductByUser($user);
    }
```

Comment: Standard authentication system work with PHP sessions but you don't have a session on your API requests, you need to use token or send credentials on each request with a custom authentication system.

Comment: look at this example with Vue js https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/data-page-load#serializing-data-directly-to-javascript